# "VBA Procedure too large" error while importing HTML Data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a code to import HTML data from a website.

It works for importing data up to 94 Excel rows. After that it gives error

> VBA Procedure too large.

I repeat the code started from `ieApp.Navigate "https://icms.indianrail.gov.in/reports/ReportServlet?reportAction=Utility&reportType=LocoCurrStatus&subAction=main`  to  `End If`  for each row.

How do I modify the code for more than 600 rows? 
    Sub GetTable()

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "https://icms.indianrail.gov.in/reports/"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .UserId.Value = "88888"
    .Password.Value = "******"
    .submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "https://icms.indianrail.gov.in/reports/ReportServlet? 
reportAction=Utility&reportType=LocoCurrStatus&subAction=main"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .trainNo.Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    .startDate.Value = Format(Date - 1, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    .submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("TABLE_6")

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("D2").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If
End Sub
```

My Excel Sheet:
[image: My Excel Sheet]

Comment: I hope you didn't just post an actual username and password here? If that is the case I believe you have to contact a moderator to delete it (from the history as well)